# cannot resolve method in Java UDF from Pig

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions, udf

I am using Pig on Hadoop and DataFu sample here (http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/set-operations.html), here is my code and error message, anyone have any thoughts what is wrong? Thanks.

```
register datafu-1.2.0.jar;
define setDifference datafu.pig.sets.SetDifference();

-- ({(3),(4),(1),(2),(7),(5),(6)},{(1),(3),(5),(12)})
input = load 'input.txt' AS (B1:bag{T:tuple(val:int)},B2:bag{T:tuple(val:int)});

differenced = FOREACH input {
  -- input bags must be sorted
  sorted_b1 = ORDER B1 by val;
  sorted_b2 = ORDER B2 by val;
  GENERATE SetDifference(sorted_b1,sorted_b2);
}

-- produces: ({(2),(4),(6),(7)})
DUMP differenced;
```

[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve SetDifference using imports:

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Try the following: check if  the path to UDF is valid `datafu.pig.sets.SetDifference();` if the path is valid, try to restart Grunt, do you still encounter it?

Comment: @Flowryn, thanks for the advice, what do you mean path to UDF is correct? More details appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't reading carefully, the problem is in another part. the package is correct and you are using a library here. I must run the code also, now I am not at the office. (Later edit: by 'path' I was meaning 'package', sorry again for confusion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@LinMa : Looks like you are using wrong case while accessing the UDF.

Alias defined to access the UDF is :

define setDifference datafu.pig.sets.SetDifference();

You have to use the alias name while using/invoking the method.

```
GENERATE setDifference(sorted_b1,sorted_b2);
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. I think I already using name "setDifference"? No?

Comment: @LinMa : in generate statement I see setDifference method name in upper case, it should be in lowercase as per your define statement.

Comment: thanks and it seems you are also using upper case -- "datafu.pig.sets.SetDifference();"? And this is why I am confused. :)

Comment: I got what you mean. Thanks and good to know it is case sensitive when using alias. :)